# How to get the head of a pointer?

Tags: c++, linux, pointers

I was wondering, what is the best way to get the head pointer of the given memory address? In example, if `p` is allocated at the address `0` with a size of `32 bytes` how can I get back to `0` from the address `12`? In other words, get back to the "main address" from an address further into its data structure. Is that possible?

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For structs this can be accomplished using `container_of` macro provided you know its type and you have a pointer to a member of it (ex. to get the pointer of the struct if you are given a pointer to a member). For memory allocations done using `malloc` this is not possible unless you have the length you've traversed or offset you're currently at.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's a C macro hence it only working with structs.

Comment: @JesusRamos: most/all standard C macros are also part of C++. i meant to say that `container_of` is not a standard C or C++ macro, at least as of C99 and C++11 (i do not know about the latest C standard, C11, but i very much doubt that it was added there). in contrast, `offsetof` is a standard macro.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Easy to define container_of using offsetof. I always forget which is the one that's standard.